# is there pandas.filter for values (not row or column labels)?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Right now I have to do the following:

```
ix=None
for ixi in [res[col].str.contains('string') for col in res.columns]:
    if ix is not None:
        ix = ix | ixi
    else:
        ix = ixi
res[ix]
```

Here is the notebook:

https://gist.github.com/denfromufa/12379b62ef6eec9252f4c9a77e46e2b1

Code fore generating input DF:

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_letters as ascl
import numpy as np

res = pd.DataFrame(np.array([''.join(_) for _ in 
                             zip(ascl[:9],ascl[9:18],ascl[18:27])]).reshape((3,3)),
                   columns='ca cb cc'.split(),
                   index='ra rb rc'.split())
```

Input DF:

```
     ca   cb   cc
ra  ajs  bkt  clu
rb  dmv  enw  fox
rc  gpy  hqz  irA
```

Desired (filtered) DF:

```
     ca   cb   cc
rb  dmv  enw  fox
rc  gpy  hqz  irA
```

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Comment: People shouldn't have to work out the nature of the question before answering it.

Comment: SO has poor support for tables, hence I linked gist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `sum(axis=1)`:

```
In [59]: res[res.sum(axis=1).str.contains('e|A')]
Out[59]:
     ca   cb   cc
rb  dmv  enw  fox
rc  gpy  hqz  irA
```

or `apply()` in conjunction with `.str.contains()` and `any()`:

```
In [51]: res[res.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('e|A')).any(axis=1)]
Out[51]:
     ca   cb   cc
rb  dmv  enw  fox
rc  gpy  hqz  irA
```

**Timing against 300K rows DF:**

```
In [95]: df = pd.concat([res] * 10**5)

In [96]: df.shape
Out[96]: (300000, 3)

In [97]: %timeit res[res.sum(axis=1).str.contains('e|A')]
1000 loops, best of 3: 664 µs per loop

In [98]: %timeit res[res.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('e|A')).any(axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop
```

**explanation:**

sum

```
In [57]: res.sum(axis=1)
Out[57]:
ra    ajsbktclu
rb    dmvenwfox
rc    gpyhqzirA
dtype: object

In [58]: res.sum(axis=1).str.contains('e|A')
Out[58]:
ra    False
rb     True
rc     True
dtype: bool
```

apply

```
In [53]: res.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('e|A'))
Out[53]:
       ca     cb     cc
ra  False  False  False
rb  False   True  False
rc  False  False   True

In [54]: res.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('e|A')).any(axis=1)
Out[54]:
ra    False
rb     True
rc     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: I will wait to see if anyone reports any special function, similar to `pd.filter`, but otherwise your answer is perfect!

Comment: @denfromufa, i've added timing - please check